# why is recipe.map not a function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data into a component, however I am getting an error it is saying recipe.map is not a component. Would love some help.

```
const App = () => {
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([]);

  const appId = `af783d30`;
  const appKey = ``;

  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${appId}&app_key=${appKey}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`;

  console.log(url);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setRecipe(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {recipe.map((r) => {
        return <RecipeCard recipe={r} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: res.data]

Comment: Default state should probably be an array instead of a string so change `useState("")` to `useState([])`. Because the initial state will be used until the API call is made and a response is received, and `map` is not a function of a string.

Comment: yes, I just changed that but still did not work

Comment: What's the output of the `console.log(res.data)`?

Comment: The response is an object and not an array, you also don't want to share your api key like that

Comment: Matt, just posted a screenshot. Asaf I changed the useState to an array but still nothing

Comment: Response `data` looks to be an object, not an array. What are you wanting to map?

Comment: Is the screenshot you have posted of recipe ?

Comment: try Object.entries . {Object.entries(recipe).map((recipes, i) => ({recipes[i]})}

Comment: ahh, I thought it would be an array since I changed its value, will try your solution khawar

Comment: your response is an object i.e. key value pairs, so you need to iterate it by using either Object.keys(obj) – returns an array of keys.
Object.values(obj) – returns an array of values.
Object.entries(obj) – returns an array of [key, value] pairs.

Comment: ah, howcome it is coming back as an object when I specified it as an array in my useState?

Comment: it is in your api response, so one should specify the state as per your response you are getting from your backend api.